# Is it okay to use the same primary key in every table?

Tags: asp.net, html

I'm designing a health care form database. We use a variety of forms, and the user id and the year are the unique identifiers. Currently I have one table per form, each with a user id and a year for the primary key: ex, table health_form_1, pk (user_id, year) various form-specific columns. table health_form_2, pk (user_id, year) various form-specific columns.

I feel weird looking at a set of tables that all have the same primary key. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I know that there is debate on this, but I strongly agree with the idea that each table should have it's own unique key, not necessarily a natural key (but it could be) for the reasons that both RedFilter and Brian Driscoll pointed out.  Expecially because business requirements change, and as such, naturla  keys change, which is a maintenance nightmare.  I've seen it make otherwise minor changes turn into a total re-write in REALLY badly thought-out apps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Database tables shouldn't map to your forms. Rather, the tables should map to real-world entities that your system is modeling.

For instance, if you are working on a medical billing system, then you might have tables like:

- Patient
- Clinician
- Invoice

etc...

Each of these tables would have its own primary key.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with that approach is that if the business requirement ever changes (e.g., the user can create the same form more than once in one year), you are in the position of having to change what your primary key is, which can be especially problematic when it is also used as a foreign key elsewhere.

Instead, I would create a surrogate autoincrement primary key for each table, and create a unqiue index or constraint on the UserID and Yeart columns instead.

Additionally, many ORMs work much better with a single PK, and it can make your queries more succinct.